# ClickOnce with expired certificate

Tags: c#, certificate

I have a project where I use click once to create the installer package. We sign this project with a certificate issued by a Vendor, not a test certificate. As we had a certificate that expired on May, we had to update the signing manifests with a new certificate.

So, we created a new certificate, signed ClickOnce manifests with this new certificate and created a new installer package. That works great with new installations but it failed to update the application because the certificates are different. According to my search, customers will have to uninstall the application and install the new version, with the new signing certificate, manually. Not cool :(

According to Robin Shahan, the best way to do this is to create a new installer that will remove the existing version (with old cert) and install the new version (with new cert). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff369721.aspx

Following the steps suggested above, I created a new package with the new certificate and set up in a different url. 
Then, I tried to create a new package with the old certificate. It failed on the  first attempt because the previous certificate was expired. The only way that I could create the package was setting my computer date to April and then create the package.

That workflow of uninstalling the old version and install the new version works perfectly, **only if the computer's date is set to past** (in my case, on April). If I try to install the package with the expired certificate, it will show the following message and I think that is the expected:

> System.Security.SecurityException: Customized functionality in this
>   application will not work because the certificate used to sign the
>   deployment manifest for SuperPlugin or its location is not trusted.
>   Contact your administrator for further assistance.

On the same article, Robin also suggests a workaround for expired certificates, using RenewCert, to create a new version with the same public/private key pair, from https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/how-to-extend-an-existing-certificate-even-if-it-has-expired/

So my idea is to create the package with old certificate with a new expiration date and once the user runs this package, it will uninstall the previous version and install the new version, with new certificate, from a different url.

So, I tried to run that RenewCert executable but I haven't had success. I have downloaded and built the project from  Cliff Stanford's website http://may.be/renewcert/ and I got this error:

> PFXImportCertStore failed with error 0x56: The specified network
>   password is not correct.

Then I got stuck...So according to Robin, if my target framework is .Net 4.0 I should not have problems, but it looks like this is not the case. I am using Visual Studio 2012, my project's target framework is .net 4.0 that is also included in prerequisites. This project was updated from 3.5 framework to 4 almost 2 years ago. Maybe that is the problem?

Ok, so my question is: how to solve this problem? Is there an easier way, just using the regular Clickonce? If the uninstall/install is the way to go, how can I change my expired certificate properly in order to create the package? If my target framework is .net 4, why is is not working?

Thanks in advance